# Self-independent random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a self-independent random variable. Show that $X$ is almost sure constant.

My proof (by condradiction): Assume that there are two disjoint Borel set $A$,$B$ such that:
$\Pr(X \in A)>0$ and $\Pr(X \in B)>0$

Since $X$ is self-independent, there must be $\Pr(X \in A)=1$ and $\Pr(X \in B)=1$.
It's a contradiction, because then $\Pr(X \in A \cup B)>1$.

Is everything ok?

Comment: it's not entirely clear why $P(A)=1$

Comment: What is definition of self independent?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then they cant both have probability 1.

Comment: Isn't that just true in general?

Comment: Because $\Pr(X \in A)=\Pr(X \in A, X \in A)=\Pr(X \in A)(PX \in A)$, there must be $\Pr(X \in A)=0$ or $\Pr(X \in A)=1$

Comment: @Kamster..no...what is A and B are perfectly correlated?

Comment: @dreamer94 Your statement in the comments is sufficient, as pre-kidney shows.

Comment: Why did you accept (25 minutes after it was posted) an answer which does not answer the question?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464264/random-variable-independent-of-itself

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**A direct proof:**

For any measurable set $A$, applying independence of the events $\{X\in A\}$ and $\{X\in A\}$ gives
$$
\mathbb P(X\in A)=\mathbb P(X\in A)\mathbb P(X\in A)\implies \mathbb P(X\in A)\in \{0,1\}.
$$
Hence $\mathbb P$ is a dirac measure. Therefore $X$ is a.s. constant.

---

**Edit, 4 years later.**

From a certain perspective, the more interesting part of the answer is the passage from "$\mathbb P(X\in A)\in \{0,1\}$" to "there exists $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb P(X=x)=1$" (the latter is the more common definition of a dirac measure), which my original answer did not address. In fact, it is a special case of a more abstract result, with $\mathbb R$ replaced by any separable metric space.

**Lemma.** Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on a separable metric space $M$ such that $\mu(A)\in \{0,1\}$ for all Borel subsets $A\subseteq M$. Then there exists $x\in M$ such that $\mu(\{x\})=1$.

**Proof.** In a separable metric space, [every open cover has a countable subcover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space). Consider the cover of $M$ by open balls of radius $\epsilon$ around every point, and extract a countable subcover. There must exist a ball $B_\epsilon$ in the countable subcover with $\mu(B_\epsilon)=1$, otherwise all balls would be null sets and thus $M$ would be null as well, a contradiction. Observe that the family of sets with measure $1$ is closed under finite (and therefore countable) intersections, from which it follows that $$\mu(B)=1,\qquad B=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}B_{1/n}.$$
Finally, diam$(B)=0$ and thus $B=\{x\}$, yielding the claim.

Answer (score 5):

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right)^2\right]
=\mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]^2
=\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]^2-\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]^2=0$$
thus $X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]=0$ a.e. .

**IMPORTANT EDIT :**
This requires $X$ to be square integrable.

Comment: What a beautiful proof :D

Comment: How do you show your upper line? $\:$ (Note that the problem does not assume $\mathbb{E}[X\hspace{.03 in}]$ exists.) $\hspace{.93 in}$

Comment: Indeed, even less that X is square integrable. Sorry but this is not the proof required (and votes on MSE are as baffling as ever).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to make this point clear : indeed, this quick proof is available provided that all quantities exist, i.e. provided that $X$ is square integrable. I add this crucial point in my post, thanks to have pointed it out.