# Proving a self independent random variable can get only one value

Tags: probability, solution-verification

I'm doing a course in probability and was asked the prove the following. I'd appreciate some feedback on it, thank you.

Let $X$ be a self independent r.v. . Prove that exists $c\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\mathbb{P}(X=c)=1$

My proof:

Let A denote the support of $X$.

Lets assume that exists $x,y\in A$ such that $x\neq y$.

Let $B_1= \{x\}$ and $B_2=\{y\}$.

So we get:
$\mathbb{P}(X\in B_1 \cap B_2) = \mathbb{P}(X\in B_1, \;X\in B_2) = \mathbb{P}(X\in B_1) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X\in B_2)=q_1 \cdot q_2 >0$

(this is true because $x,y \in A$ and have a non zero probability and $X$ is self independent).

But $B_1 \cap B_2 = \emptyset \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X \in B_1 \cap B_2)=0$ - Contradiction!

And since the support of a r.v. can not be empty we get that $A=\{x\}$ and by definition

$\mathbb{P}(X=x)=1$

Edit: Thank you for your comments, I'll fix it

Comment: Why must it be true that $P(X=x)$ has non-zero probability?  Say, for instance, that $X$ is the standard normal.  Then $A=\mathbb R$ but $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Generally speaking, I believe you need to make some assumption regarding the expectation of $X$ (like existence).  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464264/random-variable-independent-of-itself)

Answer (score 2):

By "self independent" I presume you mean $X$ and $X$ are independent.

Suggestion: Rather than looking at $P(X = x)$ which might always be $0$, consider the cumulative distribution function $F(x) = P(X \le x)$.  Show that this is always $0$ or $1$.